# Issue while accessing nested elements jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

Below is the document structure, I want to assign a value to the **Input type text = id_5**

I have code

```
var a =   $("#pl_main").contents().find("frame[name=pl_app]")[0];
console.log(a);
```

It is returning the inside document of the frame, working fine.

But I am not able to go ahead as

```
a.find("#frm_81")
```

is not working any more.

```
<iframe id="pl_main">
    <frame name="pl_App">
        <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <form id="frm_81">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="text" id="id_5" />
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
</frame>


</iframe>
```

Comment: Are you seriously having a frame tag inside an iframe tag? Why oh why???

Comment: Named frames have frameName.document - so  `var a =   $("#pl_main").contents().find("frame[name=pl_app]")[0].document.getElementById("frm_81");`

Comment: why not have the document in the frame in the iFrame directly or better: you are using jQuery, so load the html document into a div in the page instead of a frame in an iFrame

Comment: @mplungjan tried above but got error Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: @mplungjan are u around ?

Comment: Yes, but there is only so much I can try without having access to the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is a DOM object, not a jQuery object. Also named frames have frameName.document - so try this. I wanted to test, but SO does not allow iframes

```
var $if1   = $("#pl_main");
var if1Doc = $if1[0].contentWindow.document;
var f1     = if1Doc .getElementsByName("pl_app")[0];
var doc    = f1.contentWindow.document; 
var inp    = doc.getElementById("id_5"); // assuming unique IDs
```

Comment: got error  Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: Actually we should have to write  var f1 = if1Doc.getElementsByName("pl_app")[0]; and working fine upto getting value of F1 ...

Comment: @when writing last f1.document.getElementById("frm_81"); , it is giving error that
Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: @Devdotnet Do you see anything interesting if you `console.log(if1Doc)` and `console.log(f1)`?

Comment: I reached to 

var $if1 = $("#pl_main");
    var if1Doc = $if1[0].contentWindow.document;
    var f1 = if1Doc.getElementsByName("pl_app")[0];
    var docu = f1.contentWindow.document;
    var bodyObj = docu.getElementsByName("htmlBody")[0].innerHTML;
    var myObj = bodyObj.getElementById("id_5");
    console.log(myObj);
it is giving me the inner html of form , now just I have to find the input type

Comment: try `docu.getElementById("frm_81")` - it sounds promising

Comment: docu.getElementsByName("htmlBody")[0].innerHTML , it helps me to get the innerHTML , working fine , but confused how to get the input type text out of inner HTML

Comment: If you can do `docu.getElementsByName("htmlBody")[0].innerHTML` then you should be able to do `docu.getElementById("frm_81").elements`

Comment: And  `docu.querySelector("#frm_81 input[type=text]").value`

Comment: intersting , I tried  docu.getElementById("frm_81").elements , in  my context I have to assign values to the textboxes , how can I find text box using #id ? out of these